# List Of Addresses Google Maps

Tags: html, google-maps, geocoding

I would like to know if there is a way that i can get a list of addresses of a country from google maps. I would like to populate an html list box with the list of addresses. Is there a way to achieve this? I would also like to use the long and lat coordinates as the value of the address and the address description as the display value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list box with an entire country's addresses? Not only would you probably be violating a bunch of privacy laws, browsers would choke on the huge, huge list.

I work at SmartyStreets where we maintain an official list of US addresses, which is GB in size. Google and other data providers don't give handouts, and any official sets of data, which only a handful of countries maintain, are very expensive.

To validate addresses on website form entry, you'd be interested in our jQuery plugin: http://smartystreets.com/kb/liveaddress-api/website-forms

Is that something like what you're looking for? And yes, the results do come back with lat-lon.

Comment: i like your answer i was thinking about restricting this by country thou.

Comment: What do you mean by "restricting this by country" exactly?

Comment: I would only like to see addresses in a particular country or state only

Comment: There are similar APIs which attempt to do this for more than just the US; however, as I mentioned, only a few countries maintain data about actual addresses: the rest are kind of guesses.

Comment: @Matt, there must be some way to obtain a list otherwise how would Google, Zillow, or Smartystreets be able to get such data? the fact that it's a lot of data is irrelevant, it's useful data for many developers. The question pertains to "list of address" not validating an address.

Comment: @EinDoofus I do mention how to obtain the data: "Any official sets of data, which only a handful of countries maintain, are very expensive." You have to use it according to their terms which tend to be restrictive. Plus, most entities will require your software to be certified to use it. The asker asks how to obtain a list of addresses for an entire country from Google Maps. I said that it's not possible to do legally or within their usage policies. (And for the record, I no longer work for SmartyStreets, so I'm not just trying to sell something here.)

Comment: @Matt, I see that it may not be a realistic solution for most, but it would be helpful to know where one can locate some of these "entities" if they do have enough funds and law skills.

Comment: @EinDoofus Well, as I've said, each country is different. Have you thought of searching for them? The United States has the USPS, the UK has Royal Mail, Canada has Canda Post, etc. You have to find their forms and send them in, etc.

Comment: @Matt, well I'm here interacting with you, so I think it's safe to assume that I've thought about it. So it's typically the main postal carriers within the countries. Good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You usually have to pay for those kinds of data bases.  Google doesn't give you a data base dump for free and neither does anyone else.

Comment: Is there any alternative way i can do this. If i enter the address in a text item field can i use a web service to validate the address and return a suggested one?

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to validate addresses in a Map it would require some tweaking to work the way you would like it to:

http://geo-autocomplete.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/ui.demo.html